# Strange VS Android Emulator starting error

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

This is a rather strange case.  I cloned my old Intel SSD to a bigger Samsung SSD and Windows 10 failed to boot.  After fixing the bad boot sector by Windows 10 from a USB flash drive, everything seemed to work fine except the VS Android Emulator which previously worked without any problems.  The Error was "Couldn't set up the UDP port.  Some functionality might be disabled."

I reinstalled VS Android Emulator, removed and added back Hyper-v from "Program and Features" but still get the same error which I could see from the Hyper-V Manger: "Failed to read from dev/hw_random: No such device".  A search here resulted in my removing the GuestDisplayProvider entry from xdesku.xml.  After deleting all Virtual Switches and all VMs and rebooted and started VS Android Emulator again.  This time I could see in Hyper-V Manager that the VM ran fine and I could see the Android main screen.  And yet VS Android Emulator gave me the same "Couldn't set up the UDP" error.  What could be wrong?  If I put back the original Intel SSD, everything worked without any changes.  What could the Acronis clone disk missed?  BTW, I cloned the SSD from a bootable Acronis CD so it's not done within windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a problem if you have multiple switches with the same internal switch name on the same machine, and can happen during some OS upgrades.

To fix this, delete all virtual switches by going to Hyper-V Manager, going to the Virtual Switch Manager, deleting all virtual switches, and restarting the emulator (this will recreate the switches).

Answer (score 1):

This solution helped me:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f92bb80e-bf32-42f8-bd2c-2c7b8f9e840b/visual-studio-emulator-for-android-issues?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Fixed the issue by setting processor to compatibility migrate etc...

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have some applications already reserved `UDP port` for some use, and the `emulator` cannot set it up.

Since the emulator using `Socket` to connect to the host machine, it may not be accessible from the host. Some functions like `deploy` may not be perform correctly.

Comment: This gives no information that was not already in the question.